# Django: Prepopulate fields from other model or add manually

Tags: django, django-models

I can't find how to achieve the following:

Say you have two models:

- Candidates (first_name, last_name, brith_date)
- Developers (first_name, last_name, birth_date, team_name, salary, ...)

Candidates are recruited by an external company. Each morning they refresh a csv-file listing the data of all active candidates. There also is a cron job to sync the csv-file to the Django Candidates model.

Now, when an admin wants to add a new Developer to a team, he should be able to:

- Select a Candidate from the Candidate model and 'copy' the personal data into the Developer table. Team_name, salary and other fields are added manually
- When a developer is recruited not via the external recruiting company, the Admin should be able to add the personal info manually.

I could reference Candidate one-on-one in the Developers model, but this has the disadvantage that the Candidate list also has the active developers in it, and therefore can not be synced to the recruiters csv file. I would prefer just to optionally copy the personal data from the Candidates model to the Developers model, or add them manually.

Any ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is ideal for [multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance).

Example:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    dob = models.DateField()


class CandidateManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(CandidateManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
            is_hired=False
        )

class Candidate(Person):
    cv = models.TextField()
    is_hired = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False)
    objects = CandidateManager()

    def hire(self, update=False):
        self.is_hired = True
        if update:
            self.save(update_fields=['is_hired'])

class DeveloperManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(DeveloperManager, self).get_queryset().filter(
            is_hired=True
        )


class Developer(Candidate):
    team_name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    objects = DeveloperManager()
```

As you can see it pretty much writes itself and you can either write a custom [AdminAction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) to do this in the Django backend, or write a view for it.

Comment: Looks like what I need, I'll try it out. Table inheritance is new to me, thanks for pointing me there.

Comment: One question still: I would like a drop-down in the Add Developer view with the choice to add from the Candidate objects or fill in manually. Any idea on how to do that? Thanks again!

Comment: In the built-in admin?

Comment: I think adding a custom action "hire candidate" is a better option. But you can [override urls and views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#other-methods) for a ModelAdmin and even add completely new views and urls to an [AdminSite](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites).

Comment: I fixed it with a foreignfield, using ajax in the change view to autocomplete the corresponding fields on change in the foreignfield dropdown. However, I'll accept your answer, because I learned from it!

Comment: Hah, good to know and thanks. Now may I interest you in [DAL](https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/)?